# calculating parameters for defining subsections of quadratic bezier curves

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, math, geometry, bezier

I have a quadratic bezier curve described as (startX, startY) to (anchorX, anchorY) and using a control point (controlX, controlY).

I have two questions:

(1) I want to determine y points on that curve based on an x point.

(2) Then, given a line-segment on my bezier (defined by two intermediary points on my bezier curve (startX', startY', anchorX', anchorY')), I want to know the control point for that line-segment so that it overlaps the original bezier exactly.

Why?  I want this information for an optimization.  I am drawing lots of horizontal beziers. When the beziers are larger than the screen, performance suffers because the rendering engine ends up rendering beyond the extents of what is visible.  The answers to this question will let me just render what is visible.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the project?

Comment: Part 2 needs to be clarified. What do you mean by mini-bezier curve? What parameters? If you mean control points, don't you already have them for the curve?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback outis.  I rewrote (2) and added an explanation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Part 1

The formula for a quadratic Bezier is:

```
B(t) = a(1-t)2    + 2bt(1-t)   + ct2
     = a(1-2t+t2) + 2bt - 2bt2 + ct2
     = (a-2b+c)t2+2(b-a)t + a
```

where bold indicates a vector. With **B**<sub>x</sub>(t) given, we have:

```
x = (ax-2bx+cx)t2+2(bx-ax)t + ax
```

where **v**<sub>x</sub> is the x component of **v**.

According to the quadratic formula,

```
     -2(bx-ax) ± 2√((bx-ax)2 - ax(ax-2bx+cx))
t = -----------------------------------------
             2(ax-2bx+cx)
             
     ax-bx ± √(bx2 - axcx)
  = ----------------------
         ax-2bx+cx
```

Assuming a solution exists, plug that t back into the original equation to get the other components of **B**(t) at a given x.

### Part 2

Rather than producing a second Bezier curve that coincides with part of the first (I don't feel like crunching symbols right now), you can simply limit the domain of your parametric parameter to a proper sub-interval of [0,1]. That is, use part 1 to find the values of t for two different values of x; call these t-values i and j. Draw **B**(t) for t ∈ [i,j]. Equivalently, draw **B**(t(j-i)+i) for t ∈ [0,1].

Comment: Thank you for your help.  In solving the quadratic, I believe there are a couple minor mistakes in your solution?  Any event, got it to work!  Appreciated.

Comment: @jedierikb, RE: mistakes: quite possibly. What in particular are you referring to?

Comment: The mistakes that Alex Arm.'s answer corrects are some improper substitutions into the quadratic equation (and maybe an incorrect quadratic equation in the first place? Why do you have ±**2**√... ?), e.g. the divisor you provide is clearly not the `2a` that it should be

Comment: @minseong: the 2 is distributed out from the 2 factor of the coefficient of the `t` term (which comes through the quadratic `b²` term) and the 4 coefficient of `ac` from the quadratic formula: `√((2(bₓ-aₓ))² - 4 aₓ(aₓ-2bₓ+cₓ)) = ±2√((bₓ-aₓ)² - aₓ(aₓ-2bₓ+cₓ))`. You're correct about the erroneous `aₓ` term in the denominator; not sure how that got introduced.

Answer (score 2):

The t equation is wrong, you need to use eq(1)

```
(1) x = (ax-2bx+cx)t2+2(bx-ax)t + ax
```

and solve it using the the quadratic formula for the roots (2).

```
           -b ± √(b^2 - 4ac)
  (2)  x = -----------------
              2a
```

Where

```
a = ax-2bx+cx
b = 2(bx-ax)
c = ax - x
```

Comment: I just saw this now (note: with enough reputation, you can comment; users will be notified of comments on their posts).

Comment: This is what I did. Going back over my calculation, I don't see an error. What's my mistake?