# Cubic bezier curves - get Y for given X

Tags: vb.net, math, bezier, css-transitions

I have a cubic bezier curve where the first and last points are given (namely P0(0,0) and P3(1,1)).
The other two points are defined like this: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1.0) (X1, Y1, X2, Y2, also those values must not be smaller or larger than 0 or 1, respectively)
Now what would I have to do to get the Y coordinate for a given X, assuming there's only one? (I know that under certain circumstances there can be multiple values, but let's just put them aside. I'm not doing rocket science over here, I just want to be able to get Y multiple times per second to do transitions)

I managed to dig up this: [y coordinate for a given x cubic bezier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348009/y-coordinate-for-a-given-x-cubic-bezier), but I don't understand what xTarget stands for.
Oh, also this is no homework whatsoever, I'm just a bit annoyed at the fact that there's no comprehensible stuff about cubic bezier curves on the internet.

Comment: Question also appears here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348009/y-coordinate-for-a-given-x-cubic-bezier

Not sure which was first, but it may contain additional information.

Comment: @scorb p0...p3 are defined in [easing-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/easing-function).

Comment: @scorb see [Is it possible to express “t” variable from Cubic Bezier Curve equation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60113617/2521214) its for GLSL, the main idea is to convert input data to polynomial cubic and fit `t` so the resulting `x,y` matches desired state. In the example is computed distance to curve however you can easily check `x` instead.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you have

```
P0 = (X0,Y0)
P1 = (X1,Y1)
P2 = (X2,Y2)
P3 = (X3,Y3)
```

Then for any `t` in `[0,1]` you get a point on the curve given by the coordinates

```
X(t) = (1-t)^3 * X0 + 3*(1-t)^2 * t * X1 + 3*(1-t) * t^2 * X2 + t^3 * X3
Y(t) = (1-t)^3 * Y0 + 3*(1-t)^2 * t * Y1 + 3*(1-t) * t^2 * Y2 + t^3 * Y3
```

If you are given an `x` value, then you need to find which `t` values in `[0,1]` correspond to that point on the curve, then use those `t` values to find the `y` coordinate.

In the `X(t)` equation above, set the left side to your `x` value and plug in `X0`, `X1`, `X2`, `X3`. This leaves you with a cubic polynomial with variable `t`. You solve this for `t`, then plug that `t` value into the `Y(t)` equation to get the `y` coordinate.

Solving the [cubic polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_polynomial) is tricky but can be done by carefully using one of the methods to solve a cubic polynomial.

Comment: With a little help from some friends, I was able to kinda comprehend this. I rewrote two functions I got in another forum to accomplish what I needed: http://cl.ly/C1Nl (C#, may also not be pretty) Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: What is it t in this formula??

Comment: @JhansiKiRani t is whatever you want it to be, as long as it's between 0 and 1.

Comment: So can we fix it to get x,y co-ordinate??

Comment: t runs through every value from 0 to 1, where x(t=0)=X0, x(t=1)=X3. The question here is how to calculate t for for one particular x ? Note that x can have more than one t, like t=0.1 and t=0.6  might have the same x value of 0.4, but 2 different y values.

Comment: What are P0, P1, P2, and P3 in this forumala. I have a start point, an end point, and two control points. How do they map to these points?

Answer (score 1):

[image: examples of Cubic bezier curve]

P0 is your first point in the curve where t=0
P3 is your last  point in the curve where t=1
P1 and P2 are your control points.